# How to update live database from a back-up database using a where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Live database, that i'd like to take specific information from columns in a back-up database.

Here is my current query:

```
USE master;
GO
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 
   N'10.0.1.1',
   N'SQL Server';
GO

sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname ='10.0.1.1'
, @useself = 'FALSE' --specify false when using remote login and password
, @locallogin = null -- not used because we are not mapping remote and local login
, @rmtuser ='Login'
, @rmtpassword = 'Password'

Use livedatabase
GO

SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
INTO #temptable
FROM [10.0.1.1].BackupDatabase.dbo.Table

UPDATE
   Table
SET
   Table.col1 = PP.col1, 
   Table.col2 = PP.col2,
   Table.col3 = PP.col3,
   Table.col4 = PP.col4


FROM
    Table CU

INNER JOIN
    #temptable PP
ON 

    TA.col5 = PP.col5

Drop Table #Temptable

USE master;
GO
sp_dropserver '10.0.1.1', 'droplogins';
```

What I can't figure out, is how can I update the live database based on a "Where Clause"  For example, I'm looking to update:

```
Where ta.col6 = 'This is a teset'
```

I've tried this:

```
UPDATE
   Table
SET
   Table.col1 = PP.col1, 
   Table.col2 = PP.col2,
   Table.col3 = PP.col3,
   Table.col4 = PP.col4


FROM
    Table CU

INNER JOIN
    #temptable PP
ON 

    TA.col5 = PP.col5

where ta.col6 = 'This is a test'
```

This updates ALL rows in the table, and then separately the filtered rows.

I know that I need to update the "Update, Set" portion and turn the "From" into a select statement.  But I can't quite figure out how to get that to work.

Comment: what is `ta` in your query? do you mean `CU`?

Answer (score 1):

Use the table alias in the `update`:

```
UPDATE CU
    SET col1 = PP.col1, 
        col2 = PP.col2,
        col3 = PP.col3,
        col4 = PP.col4
    FROM Table CU INNER JOIN
         #temptable PP
         ON cu.col5 = PP.col5
    WHERE cu.col6 = 'This is a test';
```

When you say `UPDATE TABLE . . .` it ends up being another copy of the table.  Personally, I wish SQL Server would give an error (or at least a warning) when this happens.  That is, if the `UPDATE` has a `FROM` clause, then the `UPDATE` table should be a valid alias defined in the `FROM`.

Comment: See the end of my post.  I tried this, but it updates 2 sets.  It initially updates ALL rows in the table.  Then it separately updates the filtered "where Clause" results  For example:  
`(73932 row(s) affected)

(26 row(s) affected)`

Comment: @Shmewnix . . . The end of your post says `UPDATE table` not `UPDATE cu`.

Comment: after your changes, same result.

Comment: why is the alias used `TA` and not `CU`?

Comment: I changed it to CU per @Gordon Linoff's Recommendations